# What things are involved to access my database in Amazon Web Services from my local computer?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to create a relational database in Amazon Web Services and access it from my local computer. Do I need to create a VPC, a Subnet, a Routing Table, a Router and an Internet Gateway with a security group as well as a network access control list to access to it from my local computer? I just want to make sure if my understand is correct or not.

Comment: It depends how secure you want to be?

Comment: It is my first time to create a relational database in aws, so I don't really know different ways to create. The way I mentioned above is from some youtube tutorials. I thought I have to create all those stuff I mentioned above. I don't really understand what you meant by "how secure"/

Comment: To start with you don't have to create any of these things. The only things to do is to make your rds publically accessible and adjust security group to allow access from your IP address, or entire internet.

Comment: Do I have to do anything with the Network Access List for it, too?

Comment: No. You don't have to do it either.

Answer (score 2):

### First of all, the following is not secure and is prone to attacks.

1. Create an RDS instance, select "development" instead of "production"
2. In the setup page, under "Advance", enable "public access"
3. When creating a new security group for the RDS, open port 3306 (assuming you are using MySQL/Maria/InnoDB)
4. If you have fixed IP, you can only whitelist port 3306 to your IP address
5. On the dashboard page, copy the RDS endpoint and note the port
6. On your computer, use your favourite program (MySQL Workbench , Table Plus or anything you use), enter the endpoint , username and password and you should be good to go

### Again, this is not recommended because it is not secured. You can search for how to harden your database once you have successfully set it up though.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to worry about  a VPC, a Subnet, a Routing Table, a Router and so on. TO work with Amazon RDS, you have to setup the database (for example, MySQL) and then configure the security group to allow the IP address of your dev machine to connect. Once you do this, you can create an application that performs operations on the database.

Here is a dev AWS tutorial that creates a web application that stores data in MySQL running on the cloud. It will show you how to setup the database and the inbound rules. Once you do, you can store data or query data from MySQL. Likewise, you can use MySQL Workbench to interact with MySQL on the cloud.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/Creating_rds_item_tracker